# Can one use a mix of white rice flour with regular white flour sourdough to make a pizza crust? If so then what ratio might be the best?

Tags: rice, pizza, sourdough

I have a regular active sourdough (comprising 50% fermented white wheat flour and 50% water by weight) which is obviously not really malleable as a dough but rather liquid-ish, and I did not like the idea of adding more (non-fermented) flour to it make into a malleable dough. I am aiming to cook it in an oven to make a pizza crust. Would white rice flour be a good substitute for the non-fermented flour to add to the sourdough in order to make a malleable dough out of it? If so, what ratio might possibly achieve the best results?

Comment: Why not use wheat flour?  Why do you want to use rice flour?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @moscafj I'm using rice flour as I want to avoid non-fermented gluten and phytic acid. Sourdough is okay as it's fermented.

Comment: I just did a bit of cursory research on fermented v. non-fermented gluten.  We can't debate the science of that here.  However, why not create a pizza dough and allow it to ferment for 24 - 48 hours (that is quite common)?